# I am new to redux. I am able to access only 1 key-value at a time and the other one is not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reducers

Only getting name or task on the time of submit, 
How to receive both the key-value pairs on the same time

```
import * as actionTypes from './actions'
const initialState = {
    formData: {
        name: "",
        task: ""
    }
};

const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {

    switch (action.type) {

        case 'SAVE_FORM_DATA':
            return {
                ...state,
                formData: {
                    formData: action.payload
                }

            }

        default:
            return state;
    }
}
export default reducer;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have `{ name: "bob" }` in your payload
formData: action.payload will make `formData: { name: "bob" }`

to retain old formData you need to destructure that as well.

`formData: { ...state.formData, ...action.payload }`

```
import * as actionTypes from './actions'
const initialState = {
  formData: {
    name: "",
    task: ""
  }
};

const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {

    case 'SAVE_FORM_DATA':
      return {
        ...state,
        formData: {
          ...formData, ...action.payload
        }

      }

    default:
      return state;
  }
}
export default reducer;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by 2 methods:

1) You can just make clone of your state and do the necessary modifications in the cloned object and return it as I have shown in the example

2) Alternatively you can explore **"update in react addons"** which is used to update the parameters required while keeping the state immutable

```
import * as actionTypes from './actions'
const initialState = {
  formData: {
    name: "",
    task: ""
  }
};

const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {

    case 'SAVE_FORM_DATA':
    let jasper = Object.assign({}, state); 
      return {
        jasper:action.payload
        }

      }

    default:
      return state;
  }
}
export default reducer;
```